# Find n of Geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

I need to find the $n$ of a geometric sequence, this formula is to find the $n$th term,

$n$th = $ar ^{n-1}$;
so I need $n$ to be on the left instead of $n$th, I have all the other variables except for $n$.
I want to know the position of a number in a geometric sequence, and $n$th stands for the number which I know already, also I know $a$ and $r$ already, but I don't know the position of my $n$th term, which is $^n$ .

For example ==> $[1, 2, 4, 8, 16]$ how can I get the position of $8$ for example, which should be 4 based on that sequence.
Thanks

Comment: What ? I don't understand what do you need?

Comment: @openspace, I have edited my question, please check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a_n = ar^{n-1}$ then $n = \log_r(a_n/a) + 1$.

Comment: thanks, but it's still confusing, as there is still an n on the right side

Comment: @SeyiAdekoya, $log_r(8/a)+1 = \cdots$.